# Flutter firestore get all documents where a field contains a specific map key

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore database, I have a collection call `rooms` in which I have multiple documents, in each of those documents (a document is a room), I have a field that is a map and it is called `users`, and this is a map of an email and a display name: Expemple :

```
{
john.doe@exemple.com : "John Doe",
nemar@gmail.com : "Nemar",
}
```

etc...

How do I make a query to get all room documents that users field contains a key named after an email knowing that every key can be different depending if a user is in a room or not ? like :

```dart
firestore.collection('rooms').where('users', arrayContains: "john.doe@exemple.com").snapshots()
```

I use it in a Stream Builder...

I don't want to get all documents to after make a selection of them...

thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map is not an array, so `arrayContains` won't work here (by design).

I think you can most easily [use a not-equal condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) on the nested field here:

```
firestore.collection('rooms').where('users.john.doe@exemple.com", notEqual: "").snapshots()
```

The main problem I still see there is that the dots in the email address will be interpreted as separators for nested fields too, so you'll need to find a solution for that. I expect the trick for this to lie in using a [`FieldPath` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/FieldPath.html) in the query based on multiple strings (so: `new FieldPath("users", "john.doe@exemple.com")`), but I haven't tried that myself yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, the problem was, as you said, the points in the email address. I've corrected with FieldPath as you suggested !

Comment: In general: emails as an object key is a TERRIBLE idea, for all the reasons you've encountered and more.